# Way to make a js function accessible in Idyll?

Tags: idyll

Title says it all. I'd like to be able to transform data using the derived variable syntax, but be able to write the transforming function in a different file for syntax help and legibilitiy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject functions into Idyll by using a custom context as per the ["runtime context" documentation](https://idyll-lang.org/docs/plugin-system)

> If you want to write custom code that reads or writes to Idyll's internal state, you can use the context API. This API provides events
>   that fire whenever an Idyll variable is changed, and provides a
>   function to push variable updates.
>
> ```
> module.exports = (ctx) => {
>
>   // The context has loaded,   // initial data is available   ctx.onInitialize(() => {
>     const initialState = ctx.data();
>
>     // Once the context has been initialized,
>     // you can use the ctx.update() method
>     // to modify data
>     ctx.update({
>        key: value
>     })
>
>   })
>
>   // The application has mounted in the browser,   // the window object is available   ctx.onMount(() => {
>
>   })
>
>   // An update has been triggered,   // arguments contain only modified data   ctx.onUpdate((newData) => {
>
>   })
>
> }
> ```
>
> To configure a custom context locally, you can point Idyll to the file where you've implemented this logic, in the `package.json` config.
>
> ```
> "idyll": {   "context": "./my-context-file.js" }
> ```

Essentially you'll want to write your function, then add it to the context during the `onInitialize` event. Once you've done that, then your custom function should be usable from inside any idyll expression.